# Firebase Firestore library causes : java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am tryng to add Firebase Firestore db to my android application but i get this error:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nfciue.nfcsmartanimalpassport"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username "sdkuser"
            password "taplinx"
        }

        url "http://maven.taplinx.nxp.com/nexus/content/repositories/taplinx/"
    }
}
}

dependencies {
//noinspection GradleCompatible

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
compile('taplinx-android:nxpnfcandroidlib:1.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

also "compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'" causes warning that says:
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.8.0, 10.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1 less... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) 
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

As a beginner, these errors and warnings are complicated for me. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your app level build gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.8.0'
```

This will clear alway the "All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification".

As for the dex problem I've encountered the problem many times before and it was always fixed with using the latest version of the compileSdkVersion and of the libraries I was using.